# Server memory slowly increasing linerarly over time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vps, memory-usage

I am running an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server with a number of processes on it, mostly Apache and MySQL to support some small websites and projects I am hosting. However, over the past two months I have noticed that the server memory usage slowly creeps up daily, over the course of a week - until I reboot it.

What kind of process could be causing this increase in sustained memory usage - and is there a way to track which processes are using the most memory over time? I've monitored top and can't see anything taking up more than a few % of memory for any large period.

[Server memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exh8h.png)

(I am also aware that 14.04 is out of support, I am migrating services over time to another box.)

Comment: What is monitoring your memory, and is it doing so correctly? See https://linuxatemyram.com

Comment: Thanks for that. The graph is taken from the SolusVM stats tab .

Comment: You should check the actual numbers yourself, just to be sure.

Comment: Seems to be accurate, SolusVM reporting 754.8 MB Free and `free -m` reports 755 MB free (free+cached). Going to keep an eye on it when the usage reports creep up higher in SolusVM and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Kill all Apache processors and try when this happens without restarting the server.
This can be curse buy PHP memory leeks. It can be a php missing/depreciated function doing this. you will have to check your logs to conform that.
Make sure that the oom killer is not killing processors like mysql and apache.